# noise added to geom_line with gganimate

Tags: r, gganimate

I am seeing noise added to the output when I'm using gganimate.

```
library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-04-30"), by = "day")

x_axis <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)

d1 <- expand.grid(dates, x_axis)
names(d1) <- c('date','x')

y1 <- seq(0.15,1,length.out = length(dates))

d2 <- data.frame(dates, y1)
names(d2) <- c('date','y')

d3 <- d2 %>% left_join(d1)
#> Joining, by = "date"

ggplot(
  d3
  , aes(
    x = x
    , y = y
  )
) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_time(
    date
  )
```

This renders the following output where I am seeing the noise added to output.

[noisey gganimate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6616l.gif)

Comment: By default you get 100 frames of animation. not one for every date. So some dates are "combined" into one frame. Try specifying the number of frames you want. Like `animate(..., nframes=length(dates))`

Comment: Or use `transition_states()` rather than `transition_time()` and then you don't have to worry about the number of frames.

Comment: Adding `nframes=length(dates)` worked thank you! I did find in the production dataset I am using that I still got some noise with `nframes = length(dates)` but achieved a better looking output with `nframes=length(dates) * 3`.

On a separate note, using `transition_states()` actually dropped a bunch of the dates. I thought this may be due to something about the field being a Date format but I cast it to a factor and I still saw the same issue.

Code: https://pastebin.com/3gD1eGKD

Output: https://imgur.com/a/oUbtVvC